# Preventing Startopia visitors from walking in circles

Tags: startopia

Just after I took over an AI player's territory in Startopia sandbox mode, my visitors started walking themselves to the point of death or desertion.

They walk to the end of a line, then turn around and go back. The bunch by the roulette wheel does not move at all.

[image]

Does anyone know why this might happen or how it might be reversed? I've thought of bombing them and have already removed some nearby security columns to clear their way.

Comment: I apologize in advance if this question is out of scope; it's my first on any stackexchange site. I don't know how long that link will work; it was created automatically by the "ask question" form from my upload. Oh, and thanks in advance. This is my first sandbox station that hasn't collapsed in on itself.

Comment: That is… pretty odd behaviour. I haven't seen this before, but you could try packing up more of the buildings nearby (the roulette wheel for a start), maybe moving them elsewhere if possible. Also I'm assuming you're running the latest patches (1.01 or 1.01b)? There's an unofficial 1.02 patch, but IIRC it mostly deals with graphical issues and may be less stable than the official releases.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the duplicate buildings.

Then make sure that everyone's basic needs can be meet (hygiene, food).

You may need to rebuild and reorganize a lot of rooms and hire aliens to operate them. This is typical if you have a lot of new aliens to look after now that you've defeated the AI.

Also, the visitors often get "stuck" when they want to go to a different manager's section and they cannot travel there. Trying to take over another section (above or below) will often get theses aliens moving, as they can finally path to where they want to go while a section door is open between your part of the station and the other manager's sections. Unless you are rolling across the entire level, you will often "lose"/anger many of these stuck aliens who cannot reach their desired destination and refuse to chose something suitable in your sections instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove duplicate buildings. With the possibility to go around the entire station, the AI seems to be overburdened when trying to determine which building of a desired type is the nearest one.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have seen this poor pathing behavior only after I control most of the station, and prior to deconstructing captured (enemy) buildings. If your starports, and all other tourist buildings are clumped together (on both the engineering and entertainment decks) on one side of the station this doesn't happen. Normally most of the station segments in the end game are only needed for energy storage and stardocks on the engineering deck; just avoid building any tourist attractions that require long commutes.